# Why can't I get the input through scanf with this program?

Tags: c

Why doesn't this program take any input?
Apparently, ir is skipping all the `scanf` lines.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct student{  
    int rollno;    
    char name[10];    
    float marks;    
};

struct student s;

void main()
{   
    scanf("\n enter roll no \t %d",&s.rollno);    
    printf("enter name");    
    scanf("\n name is  \t %s",s.name);    
    printf("enter marks");   
    scanf("\n  marks are \t %f",&s.marks);   
    printf("\n s  actually  are %d \t %s \t %d",s.rollno, s.name , s.marks);   
    getch();
}
```

Comment: You may first try to search some examples of `scanf` usage?

Comment: Why are you calling `scanf` before `printf` ?

Comment: You are using scanf completely wrong, it does not do prompts.

Comment: Please remove all the prompts and tabs and newlines and spaces from the `scanf` format specifiers. For example `scanf("%d", &s.rollno); `

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaking the function of `scanf` and `printf`. Although both calls appear similar, there are significant differences between the two functions.

**printf writes output**

**scanf reads input**

In order to prompt a user to enter his name you use the `printf` function first.
Then use `scanf` accordingly to read this input.

In order to read a floating point, you can simply use;

`scanf("%f" , &marks)`

I would suggest reading through [scanf and printf basics](http://www.sitesbay.com/cprogramming/c-printf-and-scanf) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You're using scanf in the wrong way.
To achieve the result you want, try instead :

```
int main(){
    printf("Enter name: \t");
    scanf("%s", s.name);
    printf("The name is ", s.name)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` is typically used to read user input from the standard input using the format specified in its argument. You do not specify the actual message prompt in the method argument; you specify the format of the input you expect from stdin. For message prompts, `printf` is a better choice. See the following revision in your `main` function.

```
void main()
{     
   printf("\nenter roll no \t");
   scanf("%d",&s.rollno);    
   printf("\nenter name");    
   scanf("%s",s.name);    
   printf("enter marks");   
   scanf("%f",&s.marks);   
   printf("\n s  actually  are %d \t %s \t %f",s.rollno, s.name , s.marks); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your way in using `printf` and `scanf` is wrong

**printf** to prompt user input

**scanf** to read user input

then you print results in the desired format using **printf**

```
printf("enter roll number ");
scanf("%d",&s.rollno);    
printf("enter name ");    
scanf("%s",s.name);    
printf("enter mark ");   
scanf("%f",&s.marks);   
printf("\n  roll number is: %d\n",s.rollno);
printf("  name is: %s\n",s.name);
printf("  mark is: %.2f\n", s.marks);
```